# Modify socket structure to send packets to another IP

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

Say there's a client program maintaining a TCP socket connection to a server on port 10000.

Is it possible to modify the socket structure like the destination IP permanently without closing or reloading the socket and the client program using any kind of system call, and also without using `iptables`?

I would like to redirect the packets to another machine to analyze it, without breaking the connection.

Assuming I have root privileged and it is OK to modify the kernel or add kernel modules.

The host is Ubuntu Linux.

Edit: I'm well aware that I can not do that in the application layer, so I'm looking for ways to directly modify the kernel and the TCP/IP stack, is that possible? That information has to be kept somewhere in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way for an application to modify a TCP socket connection through the standard API.  To do so would break much of the state associated with the connection and there is certainly no way that TCP on the 3rd machine would accept those packets.

That said, you could rewrite the destination at the IP layer (via iptables) to have it go to the 3rd machine which would capture it (again at the IP layer), read and analyze the contents, restore the original destination, and forward it on.

If the 3rd machine actually sits on the network between source and destination machines, you don't even have to do any IP destination rewriting -- you can capture the packets as they flow through.  This is a "[man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)" operation.

Lastly, you can have your router forward all packets to the ethernet port wired to machine #3 and then capture (always at the IP layer) the copies of the packets being broadcast to it.  Or use a "dumb hub" (as opposed to a "smart switch") that forwards all packets to all ports to connection either the source or destination with machine #3.

Any packet sniffer (e.g. [WireShark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)) will do for the last two suggestions.